# error of compilation with /up{/circle{1}}

Tags: symbols, degrees

I would like to have the "degree" symbol : N°
I have  tried with : `BP N\up{\circle{1} }`
but that causes a compilation error

edit :

```
BP N\up{blablabla}
```

run well.

```
BP N\circle{1}
```

run well.

but

```
BP N\up{\circle{1}}
```

lead to the following error :

```
===> Argument of \@circle has an extra }.
```

EDITED AT 13.03 PM :

Finally i choose that way :

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[francais{babel}  
\begin{document}  
    Chapitre N\up{o}1  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post the minimal document, that causes this error. It should be `\circle`, not `/circle`, but I am unsure that your notation is correct

Comment: ok , i have just edited the typo error

Comment: Yes, but it does not solve the question, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}

N\textdegree


\end{document}
```

You only show fragments of code in your question but `\up` is not defined at all by default, and you do not show its definition and `\circle` is only intended for use within `\begin{picture}..\end{picture}`

Comment: ok, i understand now that \up is not a latex primitive.

Comment: @user3543133 You must have had an error message about that from latex?

Comment: @Carlisle \documentclass[11pt]{lettre}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

Comment: @user3543133 that's why every question should have a complete document as in this answer. `\usepackage[francais]{babel}` defines `\up` (to do nothing) so you only get no error for `\up` if you use French babel, but that was mentioned nowhere in your question.

Comment: @Carlisle [link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) textcomp is mark as "obsolete" ?

Comment: @user3543133 that's the original latex209 version textcomp is part of the core latex base release (and has been since 1993)